# Issue with Storyboard and PerformWithSegueIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to develop an application using Storyboard and Swift 2.0.
I've got a SideMenuController with a UITableView inside and a CenterViewController. Every time I click on a row on side menu I perform this action:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        self.sideMenuController()?.performSegueWithIdentifier(CenterSegue, sender: nil)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        self.sideMenuController()?.performSegueWithIdentifier(SaloniSegue, sender: nil)
    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        ...
}
```

Everything seems to work fine but during a little test, I've pointed out that older view controllers are still in the stack.

[image]

Is there a way to pop them out preventing RAM overloading?

Comment: What is your segue type?

Comment: It's a show type (eg. Push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by accessing navigationController.viewController property 
Take a look on this function... you will get some idea..
Also instead of pushing... you can performSegue if you need

```
func pushController()
{
    // Variable to check whether viewcontroller is present in memory or not
    var isFound = false;

        // searching in array of viewControllers of navigationController
        for item in self.navigationController!.viewControllers
        {
            if(item.isKindOfClass(ViewController) == true)
            {
                isFound = true;
            }
        }

    if(isFound == false)
    {
        // LoadView then push it
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: true);
    }
    else
    {
        // View Is in memory so just pop to it
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(yourViewController, animated: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I cannot use this because my `self.sideMenuController` it's not a UINavigationController but a UIViewController. Unfortunately It has not array of viewControllers to access. I would like to destroy one ViewController when other one pushes.

Comment: which type of segue you are using

Comment: Type custom, I use this controller to manage side menu. https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController

Comment: yes this control using navigationController to pushViews and this segue which you are using is of push or show type.... so this method will work here...you can try

Comment: check viewController existence with this method in navigationController before performing Segue... i think this should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying!

Answer (score -2):

First of all, change your navigation structure, get rid of hamburger/left menu, it's absolutely sux.

Comment: I like side menu structure, with hamburger left menu.

Comment: apple pushed/forced all popular apps to get rid of it... check popular apps all  disabled their hamburger menus, because in the long term it breaks app navigation experience for user, user may feel where the hell I'm in app? in which tab/menu etc.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I will try to explain to my client, indeed He likes it :-)

Comment: @turushan, doesn't look like an answer to me. It might be a comment, but definitely not an answer. -1.